We are using Hard Coded Password in SAP UI5 Standard Application
We are using Hard Coded Password in SAPUI5 Standard Application. How we change( In code level as per user requirement ). the format of password into Standard into Dynamic. If user want to edit then automatically update the new password through frontend only.
I am tried so to do some changes in code level but it's not working. I want if user want to change his password from UI it will be automatically update with new one.

I am tried so to do some changes in code level but it's not working show us what you've tried
